# What is meant by the completeness of a Hilbert space? Why do we need this property for the vector space of quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics

The quantum mechanical Hilbert space is defined as a complex vector space that is **complete** and has an inner product defined on it. Please help me understand the meaning of "complete" in this definition, and also the reason why this property is needed. Thanks.

Comment: This was already discussed https://mathoverflow.net/q/35840/

Comment: It is complete in the sense of Cauchy sequence. Many mathematical constructions actually depend on this completeness property. You can refer to this lecture notes on Quantum mechanics by Schuller : http://mathswithphysics.blogspot.com/

Comment: @KP99 Thanks, I'll look into it.